# play Framework MySQL and EBean

Tags: mysql, playframework, playframework-2.0, ebean

So I am trying to deploy my play Framework 2.3.5 on my Server. I have connected it with the MySQL database (newest version) and use EBean for persistence.

My 1.sql script looks like:

```
# --- Created by Ebean DDL
# To stop Ebean DDL generation, remove this comment and start using Evolutions

# --- !Ups

create table input (
  id                        varchar(255) not null auto_increment,
  text                      TEXT not null,
  mode                      varchar(255) not null,
  theme                     varchar(255) not null,
  title                     varchar(255) not null,
  PRIMARY KEY (id)
)
;




# --- !Downs

drop table input;
```

and for the reason i post this my error message:

```
[info] play - database [default] connected at jdbc:mysql://localhost/pastedemo
[error] play - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your     
MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'sequence input_seq' at line 1 [ERROR:1064, SQLSTATE:42000]
Oops, cannot start the server.
@6kaijj99g: Database 'default' is in an inconsistent state!
```

Can someone tell me where my fault is? :)

Comment: missing closing bracket between `PRIMARY KEY (id)` and `;`

Comment: Thank you. The error message still appears, but I edited it in the post ;)

Comment: id varchar(255) not null auto_increment ...  having a varchar autoincrement column doesn't look right.

Comment: I tried without autoincrement, the error is the same :/ but thanks for your answer!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I solved the problem. It is pretty easy.

When you want to use your application in production mode, you have to delete the 1.sql. Then use `activator dist` for packing your application and upload it on your server. **Don't test it with `run` again.**  After that you can deploy it and it works.